# onActivityResult called before setResult

Tags: android, android-activity, startactivityforresult

I have a program where onActivityResult() is being called with the correct request code, and a null intent parameter And, when that activity calls setResult(),onactivityresult is not called. onActivityResult() called after startActivityForResult()

```
public void placeListActivity(View view) {

    Intent placeListIntent = new Intent(this,
            PlaceListActivity.class);
    // startActivity(placeListIntent);
    this.startActivityForResult(placeListIntent, 5);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int request, int result, Intent arg2) {
    super.onActivityResult(request, result, arg2);


  if (request == 5 && result == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        handleOnActivityResult();
    }
```

**Second Activity:**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if(status){
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }




}
```

Comment: Please check this [example](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example). You are doing something wrong, still you are stuck then post your code and explain more, Android onActivityResult() is called properly without any bug.

Comment: this problem only for below api level 17

Comment: Post the code. Your explanation is difficult to understand. Explain what is happening and what you think should happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
```

You are only sending resultCode so intent will be received null. send Intent with resultCode in setResult method as a second parameter. You will get that intent in first activity.

[image: setResult method signature]
**Note:-** When the activity's launch mode is singleTask or singleTop, the onActivityResult will be called as soon as the activity is started with a data null. To prevent this, use Intent.setFlags(0) to reset the default flags.

Comment: my problem is onActivityResult called before setResult

Comment: this problem only for some api level.. this worked fine when i changed  my activity launch mode  to singleTop from singleTask.is this corrct way?

Comment: instead of  `finish()` write `super.onBackPressed();`

Comment: Make your activity launchMode standard and use this code

<br />

`@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("key","value");
    if(status){
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}`

Comment: What not worked, activity not destroyed or you did not get proper intent in onActivityResult?

Comment: When the activity's launch mode is singleTask or singleTop, the onActivityResult will be called as soon as the activity is started with a data null. To prevent this, use Intent.setFlags(0) to reset the default flags.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127370/discussion-between-murugan-p-and-harish-gyanani).